# How to define a complex return type without a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure with dynamic sql that I need to return an OBJECT_RESULT type. I am trying to build the complex type within visual studio through EF. The problem, I believe, is coming from the fact that the table is one of the parameters of the proc. So when EF tries to build the type and the table is null, I get the error that the selected stored proc returns no columns. I have tried setting FMTONLY off and specified the actual columns in the select statement. Any way I can achieve this? The proc:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFormFieldCDC2]
(
    @formfieldId INT,
    @C___operation INT,
    @C___start_lsn binary(10),
    @schemaname sysname,
    @tablename sysname
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    --IF (OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)) IS NULL)
    --    THROW 50000, 'Table not found', 0;

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT [__$start_lsn]
      ,[__$end_lsn]
      ,[__$seqval]
      ,[__$operation]
      ,[__$update_mask]
      ,[ID]
      ,[LookupList]
      ,[LookupColumns]
      ,[LookupAdditionalColumns]
      ,[FormFieldsID]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateEdited]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[EditedBy]
      ,[__$command_id]
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '
WHERE __$start_lsn = @C___start_lsn
  AND __$operation = @C___operation
  AND FormFieldsID = @formfieldId;
';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
    N' @formfieldId INT,
       @C___operation INT,
       @C___start_lsn binary(10)',
    @formfieldId = @formfieldId,
    @C___operation = @C___operation,
    @C___start_lsn = @C___start_lsn;
```

Comment: If you're really forced to do it though EF, I would skip the sproc entirely and do in client code by using generics. The only dynamic part here is chose one table or another.

Comment: You can't do it like this because `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` is going to fail as the output is undefined (this is how EF identifies the output). You would need to use the types you created for your tables, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set FMTONLY off.  That's an old hack that is no longer necessary.  Instead, explicitly declare the shape of the resultset, using [EXECUTE ... WITH RESULT SETS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) when you execute the dynamic SQL.  Like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFormFieldCDC2]
(
    @formfieldId INT,
    @C___operation INT,
    @C___start_lsn binary(10),
    @schemaname sysname,
    @tablename sysname
)
AS
BEGIN

/*
  declare @object_id int = object_id('GetFormFieldCDC2')
  select * from  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(@object_id,0)
*/

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    --IF (OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)) IS NULL)
    --    THROW 50000, 'Table not found', 0;

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT [__$start_lsn]
      ,[__$end_lsn]
      ,[__$seqval]
      ,[__$operation]
      ,[__$update_mask]
      ,[ID]
      ,[LookupList]
      ,[LookupColumns]
      ,[LookupAdditionalColumns]
      ,[FormFieldsID]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateEdited]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[EditedBy]
      ,[__$command_id]
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '
WHERE __$start_lsn = @C___start_lsn
  AND __$operation = @C___operation
  AND FormFieldsID = @formfieldId;
';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
    N' @formfieldId INT,
       @C___operation INT,
       @C___start_lsn binary(10)',
    @formfieldId = @formfieldId,
    @C___operation = @C___operation,
    @C___start_lsn = @C___start_lsn
    WITH RESULT SETS  
    (   
        (
             [__$start_lsn] binary(10)
            ,[__$end_lsn] binary(10)
            ,[__$seqval] binary(10)
            ,[__$operation] int
            ,[__$update_mask] varbinary(128)
            ,[ID] int
            ,[LookupList] varchar(max)
            ,[LookupColumns] varchar(max)
            ,[LookupAdditionalColumns] varchar(max)
            ,[FormFieldsID] int
            ,[DateAdded] datetime
            ,[DateEdited] datetime
            ,[CreatedBy] varchar(200)
            ,[EditedBy] varchar(200)
            ,[__$command_id]  int
        )
    );  

END
```

Then

```
declare @object_id int = object_id('GetFormFieldCDC2')
select * from  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(@object_id,0)
```

Will return the resultset metadata.